# How to properly link relative pages on a locally hosted jQuery mobile project?

Tags: jquery-mobile

So I recently started learning jQuery mobile framework and I've been practicing from my mobile phone with a code editor and everything is working fine.

I have added the jQuery libraries to my **index.html** page head like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

If I use the "multi-page" approach inside my index file everything seems to work perfectly but when I try to create an external file like: **about.html** and try to link to it, the framework would give me an "error loading page" message. The same happens when I try to link images, they won't show up.

All files are inside the same root folder so there's no need for slashes. How could I fix this and keep practicing with relative path files? I don't like having many pages inside a single document.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well have multiple html, multiple js files as controllers...

In your index.html you have the below div:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageIndex"></div>
```

Load all the respective js files which acts as controllers.

In device ready or in subsequent controllers use change page:

```
$.mobile.changePage("login.html");
```

Each individual html page will have page id:

```
<div id="pageLogin" data-role="page">
```

And its respective controller will have pageshow event to load the correct html on change page.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#pageLogin", function() { // code for page login };
```

Comment: I did everyrhing you recomended but that doesn't seem to fix the 'error loading page' message. I'm still unable to load local html files or images.